# How do you find the credit card with the best rewards/points? [US]

Tags: united-states, credit-card, reward-program

I'm using a CC that basically gives me 2% cash back on everything. It adds up, but I have a feeling that I'm not benefiting from how often I use my card. I easily put over a thousand each month on the card and pay it off each month. I have a great credit score so what card would you suggest?

Are there any specific cards that you suggest that offer international/national air miles?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

These are my favorite credit card comparison resources.

To find the best credit card in general:
http://www.creditcards.com/

To find the best rewards card based on your specific spending patterns:
http://www.creditcardtuneup.com/

Answer (score 3):

My favorite is [BillShrink](http://www.billshrink.com/credit-cards/points-advisor/index.html). It does best at trying to analyze your particular situation and then trying to figure out what card may be best.

**MOD EDIT**  Looks like billshrink.com is shut down.  From their site:

> Dear BillShrink customer,
>
> As you may have heard, BillShrink.com was shut down on July 31, 2013.
>   While we’re sad to say goodbye, we hope we’ve been able to help you be
>   better informed and save some money along the way! The good news is
>   that much of the innovative award-winning BillShrink technology will
>   still be available via our StatementRewards platform (made available
>   to customers by our partnering financial institutions). Moreover, we
>   expect to re-launch a new money-saving service in the future. To see
>   more of what we’re up to, visit Truaxis.com.
>
> We have deleted your personal information as of July 31. We will
>   retain your email address only to announce a preview of the new tool.
>   If you do not want us to retain your email address, you can opt out in
>   the form below. This opt out feature will be available until September
>   31, 2013. If you have already opted out previously, you do not need to
>   opt out again. If you have any further questions, contact us at
>   info@billshrink.com.
>
> Thanks, The BillShrink/Truaxis Team

Answer (score 1):

Check out [Creditnet](http://www.creditnet.com) or [MyRatePlan](http://compare.myrateplan.com). Both sites have comprehensive credit card comparison tools where you can input your usage habits and spending behavior and find which card is best for your needs.

Answer (score 0):

If you're getting 2% cashback on EVERYTHING, then you've got a great card (I don't even think you can get a card like that anymore). You can get great travel rewards cards with ~2% though and that's the best deal around. Don't fall for the cards that give you things like 5% on groceries, then 1% on everything else, it's never as good and they cap the 5% on anyways.

The best rewards cards at this time are:

- Barclaycard Arrival Plus - gives you 2.2% towards travel - chip card, much better usage abroad
- Capital One Venture - gives you 2% towards travel

Both of these cards' points can be used anywhere, not just from their travel service. You just purchase travel from wherever, then you login, check off the travel purchases and get reimbursed. Also, they both have no foreign transaction fees (which is great if you travel with the points they give you).

There are other cards that have close percentages, but they are usually restricted to a particular airline, or hotel, or don't have as good features.

Comment: What about cards for those of us who don't travel?

Comment: @Michael travel cards give you the best percentages. The highest you can get with a cashback card right now is 1.5% with the Capital One Quicksilver card. If you really never travel, that would be the card for you. Rewards cards for specific businesses I would avoid altogether, too inflexible.

Comment: Good source: http://www.nerdwallet.com/cash-rewards-credit-cards/

Comment: There are actually 2 cards that I know of that offer 2% on everything currently.  http://money.stackexchange.com/questions/43305/there-are-2-cash-back-on-all-purchases-business-credit-cards-are-there-ones

Comment: Interesting. The Fidelity one doesn't seem great because it has to go into a Fidelity account, but the Citi one looks pretty good.