# There are 2% cash back (on all purchases) business credit cards, are there ones for individuals?

Tags: credit-card, reward-program

I've been searching for a simple, 2% cash back (no exceptions or categories, etc etc) credit card for individuals. My capital one business CC is quite simple - 2% cash back on all purchases. I have 2 questions:

1) Is there such as card for individuals?

2) If not, is it advisable to make all individual purchases on the business CC and sort out the commingling issue each tax year?

Thanks!

Comment: If you mention the country, we can help you set up a google search, since many companies have different offers in different countries. But this is off-topic here, since these things change frequently and any list posted here would become obsolete very quickly.

Comment: Sorry, in the USA.

Answer (score 0):

[CreditCards.com](http://www.creditcards.com/cash-back.php) has maintained a fairly comprehensive list of offers for many years now.  I don't see any straight 2% offers there right now.

Answer (score 0):

There are currently 2 2% cards that I am aware of.
The [Citi Double Cash Credit Card](https://www.citi.com/credit-cards/credit-card-details/detail.do?ID=citi-double-cash-credit-card) and the [Fidelity 2% AMEX card](https://www.fidelity.com/cash-management/american-express-cards).

Good thread for Fidelity card is [here](http://www.fatwallet.com/forums/finance/885732/).  And a good thread for the Citi card is [here](http://www.fatwallet.com/forums/finance/1386753/).

Comment: I don't like the Fidelity one because it requires it to be deposited into a Fidelity account. The Citi one looks pretty awesome though.

Comment: That is true.  But from what I hear, people get the money deposited into a Fidelity cash account and then just transfer it to their bank account.  So it does require a few extra steps.  Citi card does look enticing.